# why i get that error : XML content does not seem to be XML

Tags: xml, r, parsing

i want to get `'summary_doc'` but receive an error. What should i do.

Code is below

---

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
library(XML)

base_url = "http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/"

db = "pubmed"

query = "human+genome+AND+2014"

esearch = sprintf("esearch.fcgi?db=%s&term=%s",db,query) 

search_url = paste(base_url, esearch, sep="")

search_doc = xmlParse(search_url)

retmax = 9000

new_esearch = sprintf("esearch.fcgi?db=%s&term=%s&retmax=%s",db,query,retmax)

new_search_url= paste(base_url,new_esearch,sep='')

new_search_doc = xmlParse(new_search_url)

ids = xpathSApply(new_search_doc,path="//IdList/Id",fun='xmlValue')

id_list = paste(ids, coppapse=',')

esummary = sprintf("esummary.fcgi?db=%s&id=%s",db, id_list)

sum_url = paste(base_url, esummary, sep='')

summary_doc = xmlParse(sum_url)  #this line makes error
```

---

```
Error: XML content does not seem to be XML:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there are a couple of things going on here.

First, you misspelled `collapse` (!!) which causes `paste(...)` to generate garbage. Did you even look at `id_list`??

Second, even when you fix that, you are trying to issue a GET request with a query string containing almost 8400 8-character strings concatenated together. This generates a 414 error (Request URI too long). So one way to deal this this is to make multiple smaller requests. I don't recommend that though.

This query length limitation does not apply to POST requests, so you are better off doing it this way. Note the use of `GET(...)` and `POST(...)` in the `httr` package. These functions allow you to avoid the annoying use of `sprintf(...)` to build queries, and lead to much more readable, reliable, and reproducible code.

```
library(XML)
library(httr)
url <- "http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov"
response <- GET(url,path="entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi",
                query=list(db="pubmed",term="human genome AND 2014",retmax=9000))
doc      <- content(response,type="text/xml")
ids      <- sapply(doc["//IdList/Id"],xmlValue)

result   <- POST(url,path="entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi",encode="form",
                 body=list(db="pubmed",id=paste(ids,collapse=",")))
doc      <- content(result,type="text/xml")
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. it's really really help for me. 
but have another question. 

Q: Can i see the 'doc' file?

and one more i really thank you for your answer.