# Fetching multiple pubmed abstract using r (httr)

Tags: r, xml, pubmed, pubmed-api

This is continuation for the same task I am trying to perform from this question. [Working with pubmed api in R (httr) to retrieve abstracts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69147969/working-with-pubmed-api-in-r-httr-to-retrieve-abstracts)

using the answer below, I am able to find the pubmed IDs for the abstracts of interest.

Now, I am trying to obtain the title and full text of these abstracts (as 2 columns dataframe, one for title and one for abstract text).

what I understood from the api documentation is that passing multiple IDs is possible, so I tried the code below.

```
library(XML)
library(httr)
library(glue)
library(dplyr)
####
####



query = 'asthma[mesh]+AND+leukotrienes[mesh]+AND+2009[pdat]'

 
reqq = glue ('https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term={query}')


reqq = "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=science[journal]+AND+breast+cancer+AND+2008[pdat]&usehistory=y"

op = GET(reqq)

content(op)


df_op <- op %>% xml2::read_xml() %>% xml2::as_list()

pmids <- df_op$eSearchResult$IdList %>% unlist(use.names = FALSE)
```

the code above obtains the pmids as a character, then I try to pass them to `efetch`

```
reqq1 = "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&id=pmids&rettype=abstract&retmode=xml"

op1 = GET(reqq1)

content(op1)
```

I get an error saying: ID list is empty! Possibly it has no correct IDs.

I then tried to change the format of the ID character string so they are comma separated and without quotation marks or space in-between.

```
idc = paste(shQuote(pmids, type = "cmd"), collapse = ", ")
 
idc = gsub('"', '', idc)
idc = gsub(' ', '', idc)

# Then pass them to the same code: 

reqq1 = "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&id=idc&rettype=abstract&retmode=xml"

op1 = GET(reqq1)

content(op1)
```

but I am still getting the same error as above.
What I am trying to achieve is to get xml file with the data of these abstracts (and then eventually extract title and abstract body into dataframe).
*is it possible to pass all the IDs into one fetch or these have to be sent one by one using a loop ? if you can provide some guidance or have a short script that works, will be much appreciated.*

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `reqq1` is still just a string. You may use `glue` to use actual value of `pmids`. I think you can query multiple id's together in which case you can use `paste0(..., collapse = ',')` to collapse the id's as one comma-separated string.

```
reqq1 = glue("https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&id={paste0(pmids, collapse = ',')}&rettype=abstract&retmode=xml")
op1 = GET(reqq1)
content(op1)

{xml_document}
<PubmedArticleSet>
[1] <PubmedArticle>\n  <MedlineCitation Status="MEDLINE" Owner="NLM">\n    <PMID Version="1">19008416</PMID> ...
[2] <PubmedArticle>\n  <MedlineCitation Status="MEDLINE" Owner="NLM">\n    <PMID Version="1">18927361</PMID> ...
[3] <PubmedArticle>\n  <MedlineCitation Status="MEDLINE" Owner="NLM">\n    <PMID Version="1">18787170</PMID> ...
[4] <PubmedArticle>\n  <MedlineCitation Status="MEDLINE" Owner="NLM">\n    <PMID Version="1">18487186</PMID> ...
[5] <PubmedArticle>\n  <MedlineCitation Status="MEDLINE" Owner="NLM">\n    <PMID Version="1">18239126</PMID> ...
[6] <PubmedArticle>\n  <MedlineCitation Status="MEDLINE" Owner="NLM">\n    <PMID Version="1">18239125</PMID> ...
```

Comment: thank you. I thought the code I wrote uses the actual values of `pmids`. @Ronak, this also extracted the data for all the abstracts. do you have a code that can extract the titles and abstracts from the xml?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't really extracted data from `xml` so I can't help you on that.